# object of type Reader referencing BufferedReader object can't access method readLine()

Tags: java, bufferedreader, reader

The following code gives error that it cannot find the readLine() method.
 However, it works if I replace readLine() with read()  and make few changes accordingly.

```
import java.io.*;
class Console {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
Reader in = null;
String c;
try {
      in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("type 'quit' to quit!");
      do { 
              c=in.readLine();
              System.out.println(c);
            } while(!c.equals("quit");
        } finally {
               if(in!=null) in.close();
         }
   }
 }
```

Which part is at fault here?

Comment: Additionally, use try-with-resources rather than closing the reader yourself.

Comment: What made you think it would work?

Comment: @user207421, because read() works! and  I don't see and any fundamental difference between the two methods. So if one works, the other should work , isn't it?

Comment: The 'fundamental difference between the two methods' is that `readLine()` isn't declared in `Reader`, as a glance at the Javadoc would have shown you.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare your 'in' as a BufferedReader, not as a Reader:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
```

The readLine() method does not exist for the Reader interface.

The read() method is defined in the Reader interface so any interface or class extending/implementing it will also have the read() method.
However the readLine() method is only defined in the BufferedReader interface. Even if the object declared as a Reader happens to be an instance of BufferedReader at runtime, at compile time there is an error because only the declared type matters.

Comment: I know it works if I declare it as BufferedReader but I just wanted to know why it doesn't work in the given code because BufferedReader is a subclass of Reader and it overrides the the read() as well as the readLine() methods. Why is that read() works and readLine() doesn't. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: See my edited answer. I'm not sure what's unclear for your but the readLine() method does not exist for the Reader interface

Comment: yes sir, I get it. I should have looked in the right place. I was only looking at the BufferedReader.Thanks.